# spatie Call to a member function contains() on null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I installed the spatie to Laravel permission:

but when I tried to check if the user has rule , this problem appears:

```
      Call to a member function contains() on null?
```

my code is:

```
@role('Admin')
      <p>This message appears if the user is an admin </p>
@endrole
```

note: if I check using permission like this:

```
@can('show-post')
<p>This message appears if the user is an admin </p>
@endcan
```

it work, why using role doesn't work?

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/133 Ensure you haven't put stuff in your user model that conflicts with the tool's `permissions` property.

Comment: Nothing in conflict, is there another solution?

Comment: How about a `roles` column in the database, or any function or property in the User model titled `$roles`, `roles` - `scopeRoles`, `getRolesAttribute`, etc.?

Comment: oh , thank you, you are amazing ,it was in user models :  protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'roles' => 'array'
    ];